# Unable to insert Date() value into SQLite DB

Tags: actionscript, sqlite, flex-mobile

I am attempting to insert data into a SQLite database, including a date column. However when I execute the query in the code below the `LastLogin` field is never populated. Also, the `Created` field is also left empty, even though the default value is `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. All other fields in the query populate correctly. Can anyone tell me why this is?

This is the table SQL in SQLite:

```
CREATE TABLE [User] (
    [Id] INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    [CredentialsToken] TEXT  NULL,
    [GivenName] TEXT  NULL,
    [FamilyName] TEXT  NULL,
    [Created] DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NULL,
    [LastUpdated] DATE  NULL,
    [LastLogin] DATE  NULL
)
```

This is my AS inserting the data:

```
private const CREATE_USER:String = "INSERT INTO User (Id, CredentialsToken, GivenName, FamilyName, LastLogin) VALUES (:id, :token, :givenName, :familyName, :lastLogin)";

public function createUser(args:Array):void
{           
    if (args[0] is DatabaseResponder && args[1] is Object)
    {
        var sqlWrapper:SQLWrapper = this.sqlStatementFactory.newInstance(args[0], CREATE_USER);
        var user:Object = args[1];
        sqlWrapper.statement.parameters[":id"] = user.Id; 
        sqlWrapper.statement.parameters[":token"] =  user.LoginToken;
        sqlWrapper.statement.parameters[":givenName"] = user.GivenName;
        sqlWrapper.statement.parameters[":familyName"] = user.FamilyName;
        sqlWrapper.statement.parameters[":lastLogin"] = new Date(); // this field is always empty
        sqlWrapper.statement.execute();
    }
}
```

Also worth noting is the fact that when I execute the following SQL through SQLite Administrator, the `LastLogin` field is still left empty, although `Created` does get populated.

```
INSERT INTO User (Id, CredentialsToken, GivenName, FamilyName, LastLogin) VALUES (111, 'XYZ', 'Foo', 'Bar', '29-10-2013')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, that Date object will be passed as a parameter correctly.
Try this:

```
sqlWrapper.statement.parameters[":lastLogin"] = (new Date()).toISOString();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. `toISODateString` causes a 'function not recognised' error. The previous answer of `toDateString` does not cause a sytnax error, although it doesn't work as it raises an error event. I'm now trying to figure out why this is.

Comment: Thanks for coming back. I actually found out there was no problem. The issue was in SQLite Administrator not displaying the date fields correctly as they need to be selected using a Julian->String conversion, like this `STRFTIME('%J', LastLogin)`. Thanks.